Enterprise value in terms of market cap, debt and cash
The formula for EV is
EV = MC + debt - cash
It represents the cost to buy a firm right? Because you assume its debts and its cash will be yours.
So,
If MC = 100 billion,
Debt= 0
Cash = 1000 billion
EV= 100B + 0 - 100B = 0
So according to this i can walk in with 0 dollars and buy a company with 100B in MC and 100B in cash... but i am sure i cannot. So what do i miss here?

You can certainly try. What do you think will happen ?

Do you know the answer to my question?


It represents the cost to buy a firm right?

No, it represents the monetary value of the business itself, excluding its liquid assets. The cash a business holds is directly represented in the Market Cap (a business is worth at least the net value of its assets), so it is excluded. What you are left with is the value of the operations, property, brands, strategy, people, etc. that are created by the organization on top of its liquid assets (plus whatever debt it has accumulated).
For your example, a business with 100B in cash and 100B Market Cap adds no value on top of the cash it holds.  If you wanted to "buy the business" you would first have to "buy" the liquid assets of $100B, but then you could get the rest of the business "for free" (assuming the owners were willing to sell for the EV, of course, which is usually not the case).

That's assuming the current owners are willing to sell. Generally you have to offer enough to offset their expectations of future profit. I wouldn't give up my house for much less than twice its paper value or equivalent considerations.

Very true - I added that part.

I don't understand. I thought MC was separate from cash. Isn't the MC = share price x # of shares? Where is cash here?

cash would be part of the share price, and hence the Market Cap. If you own 10% of the assets a company, cash would be part of those assets.  Or, of a company that had $1M in cash and nothing else and had 1M shares outstanding, each share would be worth $1

If cash is part of share price why is the cash separately written than MC in the formula? When a firm issues stocks, it doesn't issue cash with it for example..

"Because you assume its debts and its cash will be yours." - no, they will belong to the seller. As the buyer, you are buying the business. A useful way to think of EV, a.k.a. 'firm value', is the value of the "going concern" - the business itself without any debts or cash. To get an intuition for the formula, work some examples like Apple (lots of cash) and AT&T (lots of debt).

The EV is the net cash needed to buy the business.
If you start with 100B and buy the business, you'll end up with 100B, so buying the business didn't cost you anything. You could also get a loan for 100B, then once you buy the business, you can use the 100B to pay the loan back (ignoring interest).
